# Printing tensorflow tensor in Python hangs forever

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to print a python tensor in a simple program.  The program reads the iris data set from a file using a tensorflow reader.  If I uncomment the last line of the program, it hangs forever.  The goal is to print sepal_length, sepal_width, etc.  What do I have to do to print the sepal_length tensor????

```
import tensorflow as tf

def read_csv(batch_size, file_name, record_defaults):
    filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(["iris.data"])

    reader = tf.TextLineReader(skip_header_lines=1)
    key, value = reader.read(filename_queue)

    # decode_csv will convert a Tensor from type string (the text line) in
    # a tuple of tensor columns with the specified defaults, which also
    # sets the data type for each column
    decoded = tf.decode_csv(value, record_defaults=record_defaults)

    # batch actually reads the file and loads "batch_size" rows in a single tensor
    return tf.train.shuffle_batch(decoded,
                                  batch_size=batch_size,
                                  capacity=batch_size * 50,
                                  min_after_dequeue=batch_size)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

    sepal_length, sepal_width, petal_length, petal_width, label =\
        read_csv(100, "iris.data", [[0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [""]])

    print("sepal_length:\n", sepal_length)

    # uncommenting the following line makes the program hang forever
    # print(sess.run(sepal_length))
```

Here is the iris.data input file:

```
SepalLengthCm,SepalWidthCm,PetalLengthCm,PetalWidthCm,Species
5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.9,3.0,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.7,3.2,1.3,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.6,3.1,1.5,0.2,Iris-setosa
5.0,3.6,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
5.4,3.9,1.7,0.4,Iris-setosa
4.6,3.4,1.4,0.3,Iris-setosa
5.0,3.4,1.5,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.4,2.9,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.9,3.1,1.5,0.1,Iris-setosa
5.4,3.7,1.5,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.8,3.4,1.6,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.8,3.0,1.4,0.1,Iris-setosa
4.3,3.0,1.1,0.1,Iris-setosa
5.8,4.0,1.2,0.2,Iris-setosa
5.7,4.4,1.5,0.4,Iris-setosa
5.4,3.9,1.3,0.4,Iris-setosa
5.1,3.5,1.4,0.3,Iris-setosa
5.7,3.8,1.7,0.3,Iris-setosa
5.1,3.8,1.5,0.3,Iris-setosa
5.4,3.4,1.7,0.2,Iris-setosa
5.1,3.7,1.5,0.4,Iris-setosa
4.6,3.6,1.0,0.2,Iris-setosa
5.1,3.3,1.7,0.5,Iris-setosa
4.8,3.4,1.9,0.2,Iris-setosa
5.0,3.0,1.6,0.2,Iris-setosa
5.0,3.4,1.6,0.4,Iris-setosa
5.2,3.5,1.5,0.2,Iris-setosa
5.2,3.4,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.7,3.2,1.6,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.8,3.1,1.6,0.2,Iris-setosa
5.4,3.4,1.5,0.4,Iris-setosa
5.2,4.1,1.5,0.1,Iris-setosa
5.5,4.2,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.9,3.1,1.5,0.1,Iris-setosa
5.0,3.2,1.2,0.2,Iris-setosa
5.5,3.5,1.3,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.9,3.1,1.5,0.1,Iris-setosa
4.4,3.0,1.3,0.2,Iris-setosa
5.1,3.4,1.5,0.2,Iris-setosa
5.0,3.5,1.3,0.3,Iris-setosa
4.5,2.3,1.3,0.3,Iris-setosa
4.4,3.2,1.3,0.2,Iris-setosa
5.0,3.5,1.6,0.6,Iris-setosa
5.1,3.8,1.9,0.4,Iris-setosa
4.8,3.0,1.4,0.3,Iris-setosa
5.1,3.8,1.6,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.6,3.2,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
5.3,3.7,1.5,0.2,Iris-setosa
5.0,3.3,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
7.0,3.2,4.7,1.4,Iris-versicolor
6.4,3.2,4.5,1.5,Iris-versicolor
6.9,3.1,4.9,1.5,Iris-versicolor
5.5,2.3,4.0,1.3,Iris-versicolor
6.5,2.8,4.6,1.5,Iris-versicolor
5.7,2.8,4.5,1.3,Iris-versicolor
6.3,3.3,4.7,1.6,Iris-versicolor
4.9,2.4,3.3,1.0,Iris-versicolor
6.6,2.9,4.6,1.3,Iris-versicolor
5.2,2.7,3.9,1.4,Iris-versicolor
5.0,2.0,3.5,1.0,Iris-versicolor
5.9,3.0,4.2,1.5,Iris-versicolor
6.0,2.2,4.0,1.0,Iris-versicolor
6.1,2.9,4.7,1.4,Iris-versicolor
5.6,2.9,3.6,1.3,Iris-versicolor
6.7,3.1,4.4,1.4,Iris-versicolor
5.6,3.0,4.5,1.5,Iris-versicolor
5.8,2.7,4.1,1.0,Iris-versicolor
6.2,2.2,4.5,1.5,Iris-versicolor
5.6,2.5,3.9,1.1,Iris-versicolor
5.9,3.2,4.8,1.8,Iris-versicolor
6.1,2.8,4.0,1.3,Iris-versicolor
6.3,2.5,4.9,1.5,Iris-versicolor
6.1,2.8,4.7,1.2,Iris-versicolor
6.4,2.9,4.3,1.3,Iris-versicolor
6.6,3.0,4.4,1.4,Iris-versicolor
6.8,2.8,4.8,1.4,Iris-versicolor
6.7,3.0,5.0,1.7,Iris-versicolor
6.0,2.9,4.5,1.5,Iris-versicolor
5.7,2.6,3.5,1.0,Iris-versicolor
5.5,2.4,3.8,1.1,Iris-versicolor
5.5,2.4,3.7,1.0,Iris-versicolor
5.8,2.7,3.9,1.2,Iris-versicolor
6.0,2.7,5.1,1.6,Iris-versicolor
5.4,3.0,4.5,1.5,Iris-versicolor
6.0,3.4,4.5,1.6,Iris-versicolor
6.7,3.1,4.7,1.5,Iris-versicolor
6.3,2.3,4.4,1.3,Iris-versicolor
5.6,3.0,4.1,1.3,Iris-versicolor
5.5,2.5,4.0,1.3,Iris-versicolor
5.5,2.6,4.4,1.2,Iris-versicolor
6.1,3.0,4.6,1.4,Iris-versicolor
5.8,2.6,4.0,1.2,Iris-versicolor
5.0,2.3,3.3,1.0,Iris-versicolor
5.6,2.7,4.2,1.3,Iris-versicolor
5.7,3.0,4.2,1.2,Iris-versicolor
5.7,2.9,4.2,1.3,Iris-versicolor
6.2,2.9,4.3,1.3,Iris-versicolor
5.1,2.5,3.0,1.1,Iris-versicolor
5.7,2.8,4.1,1.3,Iris-versicolor
6.3,3.3,6.0,2.5,Iris-virginica
5.8,2.7,5.1,1.9,Iris-virginica
7.1,3.0,5.9,2.1,Iris-virginica
6.3,2.9,5.6,1.8,Iris-virginica
6.5,3.0,5.8,2.2,Iris-virginica
7.6,3.0,6.6,2.1,Iris-virginica
4.9,2.5,4.5,1.7,Iris-virginica
7.3,2.9,6.3,1.8,Iris-virginica
6.7,2.5,5.8,1.8,Iris-virginica
7.2,3.6,6.1,2.5,Iris-virginica
6.5,3.2,5.1,2.0,Iris-virginica
6.4,2.7,5.3,1.9,Iris-virginica
6.8,3.0,5.5,2.1,Iris-virginica
5.7,2.5,5.0,2.0,Iris-virginica
5.8,2.8,5.1,2.4,Iris-virginica
6.4,3.2,5.3,2.3,Iris-virginica
6.5,3.0,5.5,1.8,Iris-virginica
7.7,3.8,6.7,2.2,Iris-virginica
7.7,2.6,6.9,2.3,Iris-virginica
6.0,2.2,5.0,1.5,Iris-virginica
6.9,3.2,5.7,2.3,Iris-virginica
5.6,2.8,4.9,2.0,Iris-virginica
7.7,2.8,6.7,2.0,Iris-virginica
6.3,2.7,4.9,1.8,Iris-virginica
6.7,3.3,5.7,2.1,Iris-virginica
7.2,3.2,6.0,1.8,Iris-virginica
6.2,2.8,4.8,1.8,Iris-virginica
6.1,3.0,4.9,1.8,Iris-virginica
6.4,2.8,5.6,2.1,Iris-virginica
7.2,3.0,5.8,1.6,Iris-virginica
7.4,2.8,6.1,1.9,Iris-virginica
7.9,3.8,6.4,2.0,Iris-virginica
6.4,2.8,5.6,2.2,Iris-virginica
6.3,2.8,5.1,1.5,Iris-virginica
6.1,2.6,5.6,1.4,Iris-virginica
7.7,3.0,6.1,2.3,Iris-virginica
6.3,3.4,5.6,2.4,Iris-virginica
6.4,3.1,5.5,1.8,Iris-virginica
6.0,3.0,4.8,1.8,Iris-virginica
6.9,3.1,5.4,2.1,Iris-virginica
6.7,3.1,5.6,2.4,Iris-virginica
6.9,3.1,5.1,2.3,Iris-virginica
5.8,2.7,5.1,1.9,Iris-virginica
6.8,3.2,5.9,2.3,Iris-virginica
6.7,3.3,5.7,2.5,Iris-virginica
6.7,3.0,5.2,2.3,Iris-virginica
6.3,2.5,5.0,1.9,Iris-virginica
6.5,3.0,5.2,2.0,Iris-virginica
6.2,3.4,5.4,2.3,Iris-virginica
5.9,3.0,5.1,1.8,Iris-virginica
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out, here is the working program:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def read_csv(batch_size, file_name, record_defaults):
    filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(["iris.data"])

    reader = tf.TextLineReader(skip_header_lines=1)
    key, value = reader.read(filename_queue)

    # decode_csv will convert a Tensor from type string (the text line) in
    # a tuple of tensor columns with the specified defaults, which also
    # sets the data type for each column
    decoded = tf.decode_csv(value, record_defaults=record_defaults)

    # batch actually reads the file and loads "batch_size" rows in a single tensor
    return tf.train.shuffle_batch(decoded,
                                  batch_size=batch_size,
                                  capacity=batch_size * 50,
                                  min_after_dequeue=batch_size)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

    sepal_length, sepal_width, petal_length, petal_width, label =\
        read_csv(100, "iris.data", [[0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [""]])

    # adding these 2 lines fixed the hang forever problem
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)

    print("sepal_length:\n", sepal_length)

    # uncommenting the following line used to make the program hang forever
    print(sess.run(sepal_length))
```

Comment: Did you figure out why it was hanging and why this fixed it?

Comment: I ran into this problem. I was using a script I didn't write to preprocess my data and that script was using a queue. If you dont start queue runners you will get this hanging behavior

Comment: Agreed - you have to start the queue runners.