# Tensorflow hangs when sess.run() is called

Tags: python, session, tensorflow

The following code will hang (only a <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>z</kbd> gets me out).

```python
import tensorflow as tf
import cifar10 # from https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/tutorials/image/cifar10 (both cifar10.py & cifar10_input.py)

def main():
    print 'TensorFlow version: ',tf.__version__

    with tf.Session() as sess:

    with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
        images, labels = cifar10.distorted_inputs()

    input = tf.constant([[[1, 2, 3], [5, 5, 5]], [[4, 5, 6], [7, 7, 7]], [[7, 8, 9], [9, 9, 9]]])

    one=input[0]
    print "X1 ",type(input), one
    oneval = sess.run(one)
    print "X2 ",type(one), one, type(oneval), oneval

    two=images[0]
    print "Y1 ",type(images), two
    twoval = sess.run(two)
    print "Y2 ",type(two), two, type(twoval), twoval

main()
```

I get the following output (with Python 2.7.5):

```python
[gpu@centos-7-4 demo]$ python demo.py
TensorFlow version:  1.2.1
2017-07-31 16:06:45.503157: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] >The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-07-31 16:06:45.503182: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-07-31 16:06:45.503187: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
Filling queue with 20000 CIFAR images before starting to train. This will take a few minutes.
X1  class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'> Tensor("strided_slice:0", shape=(2, 3), dtype=int32)
X2  class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'> Tensor("strided_slice:0", shape=(2, 3), dtype=int32) <type 'numpy.ndarray'> [[1 2 3] [5 5 5]]
Y1  class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'> Tensor("strided_slice_1:0", shape=(24, 24, 3), dtype=float32)
^Z
```

Anyone have any suggestions (or solutions)?

If anyone is interested in the background, my ultimate goal is to convert the tensor returned by `distorted_inputs()` into a set of JSON objects. So the naive plan is to iterate through each element of images and pull out the values.

Comment: How long have you left it? I think that it's probably just taking a while to load the images. Are you running it on a CPU or GPU?

Comment: It's been running for 5 minutes now. A top shows no activity. strace shows FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE. And when I run the real program (cifar10_train.py), it immediately starts running batches so I would not expect a delay.

Comment: It's all on the CPU (as far as I know) - running in a VM with no access to a GPU. I assumed TensorFlow knows there is no GPU.

Answer (score 6):

I found the answer here [Printing tensorflow tensor in Python hangs forever](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43334338/printing-tensorflow-tensor-in-python-hangs-forever)

Key was the two lines:

```
coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with TF 1.7, downgraded to 1.3 and it works fine.

Comment: I don't think downgrading is the choice to make.